# Python: Plot pie chart for every groups in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pie-chart

Below is the data frame retrieved after grouping my data set:

```
df1 = data.groupby(['gender','Segment']).agg(Total_Claim = ('claim_amount', 'sum'))
df1['Total_Claim']=df1['Total_Claim'].astype(int)
df1
```

The output of the same is:

```
                    Total_Claim
gender  Segment 
Female  Gold        2110094
        Platinum    2369761
        Silver      1897617
Male    Gold        2699208
        Platinum    2096489
        Silver      2347217
```

What would be the most efficient way of plotting a pie chart between the aggregated value of claim amount based on gender and segment?

Comment: Do you need `2` pie charts from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, I think that would be the only way to present the data.

Comment: Yes, this would work @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Series` and ploting by [`Series.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html) and `autopct` parameter for percentages:

```
df['Total_Claim'].plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

[image: g]

Comment: How can I display the labels in percentage for the chart?

Comment: @GautamMishra - What `age` ? There are no data in sample DataFrame for `age`.

Comment: I meant percentage!

Comment: using `autopct='%1.1f%%'` worked for percentage. Thanks!